# Docker Container in host mode - Reverse proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, networking

I have an issue with the docker network `host` mode. Basically I have a Node.js container running on a local network and I need to access it via a ssh tunnel from a server on the cloud. The server in the cloud has an nginx configuration so that the requests to test.endpoint.com are redirected to my on-premise Node.js container. The nginx configuration looks like that and works fine when my container is not in host mode.

```
http {
       map $host $target_port {
        test.endpoint.com 40003; 
       }
...
}
```

When my container is not in `host`mode, it works fine and my ssh tunnel works like a charm. However, when I am in `host`mode, it does not work any more.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file I am using:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  
  # listen on port 3001
  backend-with-host:
    image: my-image
    restart: always
    network_mode: host

  #backend-without-host:
  #  image: my-image
  #  restart: always
  #  ports:
  #    - 48645:3001
```

I am using autossh to create and persist the tunnel as follow (PORT being 3001 in host mode and 48645 otherwise):

```
/usr/bin/autossh -M 20000 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "ProxyCommand nc -p 56955 %h %p" -i “/path/my-key.pem" -f -N -S /tmp/session1 -R $PORT:localhost:40003 user@endpoint.com
```

The tunnel works fine when not in host mode.

When I look at the Listening ports with netstat, I have two different results:

**Host mode**

```
backend- 940685      root  24u IPv6 4646919   0t0 TCP *:3001 (LISTEN)
```

**Default mode**

```
docker-pr 939455      root  4u IPv4 4640861   0t0 TCP *:48645 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 939460      root  4u IPv6 4640868   0t0 TCP *:48645 (LISTEN)
```

Thank you for your help !